# How to search historic information from IBM Bluemix Weather Almanac API

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather-api

I need to receive some information from **Weather Company Data For IBM Bluemix APIs** about a specific period (from jan 2012 to jan 2015).

The documentation includes this example API:

https://twcservice.mybluemix.net:443/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/almanac/daily.json?units=e&start=0112&end=0115

But this is the result:

```
{"metadata":{"transaction_id":"1472145329818:-319071226","status_code":400},"success":false,"errors":[{"error":{"code":"PVE-0003","message":"The field 'start' contains a value '112' which is outside the expected range of [1 to 12]."}}]}
```

Can you let me know how I can search the historic information?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://twcservice.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/almanac/daily.json?start=0112&end=0115&units=e

It works for me!!

```css
{
  "metadata": {
    "language": "en-US",
    "transaction_id": "1501849033676:-1423101749",
    "version": "1",
    "latitude": 33.4,
    "longitude": -83.42,
    "units": "e",
    "expire_time_gmt": 1501869684,
    "status_code": 200
  },
  "almanac_summaries": [
    {
      "class": "almanac",
      "station_id": "095988",
      "station_name": "MONTICELLO",
      "almanac_dt": "0112",
      "interval": "D",
      "avg_hi": 56,
      "avg_lo": 28,
      "record_hi": 75,
      "record_hi_yr": 1916,
      "record_lo": 0,
      "record_lo_yr": 1982,
      "mean_temp": 42,
      "avg_precip": 0.13,
      "avg_snow": 0.1,
      "record_period": 30
    },
    {
      "class": "almanac",
      "station_id": "095988",
      "station_name": "MONTICELLO",
      "almanac_dt": "0113",
      "interval": "D",
      "avg_hi": 56,
      "avg_lo": 28,
      "record_hi": 77,
      "record_hi_yr": 1911,
      "record_lo": 8,
      "record_lo_yr": 1918,
      "mean_temp": 42,
      "avg_precip": 0.12,
      "avg_snow": 0,
      "record_period": 30
    },
    {
      "class": "almanac",
      "station_id": "095988",
      "station_name": "MONTICELLO",
      "almanac_dt": "0114",
      "interval": "D",
      "avg_hi": 56,
      "avg_lo": 28,
      "record_hi": 78,
      "record_hi_yr": 1937,
      "record_lo": 10,
      "record_lo_yr": 1918,
      "mean_temp": 42,
      "avg_precip": 0.13,
      "avg_snow": 0,
      "record_period": 30
    },
    {
      "class": "almanac",
      "station_id": "095988",
      "station_name": "MONTICELLO",
      "almanac_dt": "0115",
      "interval": "D",
      "avg_hi": 56,
      "avg_lo": 28,
      "record_hi": 80,
      "record_hi_yr": 1932,
      "record_lo": 11,
      "record_lo_yr": 1964,
      "mean_temp": 42,
      "avg_precip": 0.12,
      "avg_snow": 0,
      "record_period": 30
    }
  ]
}
```